# Probability of two Boolean functions being equal expressed in terms of the maximum Fourier coefficient

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, boolean-algebras

[This paper by Maslov et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-021-01271-7) uses that the probability of two $n$-bit Boolean functions $l(x)$ and $g(x)$ being equal is bound in terms of $\hat{g}_\text{max}$, the largest Fourier coefficient of $g(x)$, in the following way (between Eq. (4) and (5) of the *Methods* section at the end of the paper):
\begin{equation}
\Pr[l(x)=g(x)]\leq\frac{1}{2}(1+\hat{g}_{\text{max}}).
\end{equation}
Here, the binary Fourier transform of the Boolean function $g : \{0,1\}^n\mapsto\{0,1\}$ is defined as (with $x\cdot y$ the bitwise inner product between $n$-bit strings $x,y\in\{0,1\}^n$)
\begin{equation}
\hat{g}(y)=2^{-n}\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n}(-1)^{x\cdot y+g(x)},
\end{equation}
and $\hat{g}_\text{max}$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\hat{g}_\text{max}=\max_{y\in\{0,1\}^n}|\hat{g}(y)|.
\end{equation}
I've tried understanding this myself, as well as going over literature concerning the Boolean Fourier transform (as, for example, these texts by Ryan O'Donnell ([1](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/papers/Analysis-of-Boolean-Functions-by-Ryan-ODonnell.pdf) and [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0314.pdf)) and [Ronald de Wolf](https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/gs001/gs001.pdf)), but I haven't been able to see why the inequality holds. I got as far as realizing that the Fourier transform of $g(x)$ allows for the following relations:
\begin{equation}
g(x)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1-\sum_{y\in\{0,1\}^n}\hat{g}(y)(-1)^{y\cdot x}\bigg)\leq\frac{1}{2}(1+2^n\hat{g}_\text{max}).
\end{equation}
This, however, does not seem to be particularly useful. Any nudge in the right direction would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the RHS is independent of $l(x)$, the statement should only be true if $l(x)$ lies in a restricted subset of Boolean functions. I cannot read the paper linked, but I suspect it is intended to restrict $l(x)$ to linear functions, i.e. $l(x)=l_y(x)=x\cdot y$.

In that case it is easy to show
$$Pr\left[l_y(x)=g(x)\right] = \frac12 \left(1 + \hat{g}(y)\right)$$
and the result follows by taking the absolute value, then the triangle inequality, then the max over all $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are completely right that they restrict $l(x)$ to linear functions: I now see the importance of that restriction. It then follows that $\hat{g}(y)=\mathbb{E}[(-1)^{x\cdot y + g(x)}]=\Pr[l_y(x)=g(x)]-\Pr[l_y(x)=g(x)+1]$. Given that $\Pr[l_y(x)=g(x)+1]=1-\Pr[l_y(x)=g(x)]$, we have $\Pr[l_y(x)=g(x)]=\frac{1}{2}(1+\hat{g}(y))$.